# Entity Framework Selecting columns from multiple tables (for ThenInclude)?

Tags: entity-framework-6

I have question about select...

```
var applicationUser = unitOfWork.ApplicationUsers.GetAll().Include(i => i.ApplicationUserRoles).ThenInclude(i => i.ApplicationRole)
.Where(i => i.UserName.ToUpper() == userName.ToUpper())
.Select(i => new
{
    i.Email,
    i.FirstName,
    i.LastName,
    i.PhoneNumber,
    i.ImageUrl,
    i.JoinedDate,
    i.DateOfBirth,
    i.ApplicationUserRoles
})
.FirstOrDefault();
```

I cant get ApplicationRole how to use it in select ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using projection with `Select` you don't need to use `Include`. Just select the values. To get the Roles via the UserRoles you will need to `Select` to retrieve those:

```
var applicationUser = unitOfWork.ApplicationUsers.GetAll()
.Where(i => i.UserName.ToUpper() == userName.ToUpper())
.Select(i => new
{
    i.Email,
    i.FirstName,
    i.LastName,
    i.PhoneNumber,
    i.ImageUrl,
    i.JoinedDate,
    i.DateOfBirth,
    ApplicationRoles = i.ApplicationUserRoles.Select(x => x.ApplicationRole).ToList()
})
.FirstOrDefault();
```

You can further refine this by sub-selecting just the role details you need from the application role...

```
    // ...
    ApplicationRoles = i.ApplicationUserRoles.Select(x => 
       x.ApplicationRole.Select(ar => new { ar.RoleId, ar.RoleName })).ToList()
```

I recommend using `SingleOrDefault` rather than `FirstOrDefault` if you are expecting at most 1 result. `First`/`FirstOrDefault` should always be used with an `OrderBy`/`OrderByDescending` condition to ensure predictable results.

Answer (score 0):

If I can use for ApplicationRoles, it is working

```
.Select(i => new
{i.Email,i.FirstName,i.LastName,i.PhoneNumber,i.ImageUrl,i.JoinedDate,i.DateOfBirth,
ApplicationRoles = i.ApplicationUserRoles.Select(x => x.ApplicationRole).ToList(),
})
```

I cant use for ApplicationUserRoles how is it work for it ?

```
public class ApplicationUserSummary
{
    public DateTime JoinedDate { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ApplicationRole> ApplicationRoles { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> ApplicationUserRoles { get; set; }
}
```